# C# - ScrapySharp - how to get the <title> from the <head>?

Tags: c#, web-scraping, scrapysharp

I want to get the title from a webpage through ScrapySharp. With CssSelect, I'm only getting the `<body>` tag.

I am using it like:

```
string SearchQuery = PageResult.Html.CssSelect(".breadcrump-summary").First().InnerText;
```

Comment: Maybe you could try returning the entire website and breaking it down from there? Shouldn't take too long to iterate until you reach the `<head>`?

Comment: that's a possibility. But there must be a method to get directly to the head-tag. the other ones are no problem.

Comment: I agree with you but I don't have the website nor have I used ScrappySharp. I'd like to think it is similar to HMTL Agility Pack